# android- How to handle the Web service Exception

Tags: android

My application have 3 Relative Layouts and 3 Linear Layouts. Based on the web service response we can fill the relative and linear layout views. When you click on the relative layout then linear layout will be visible that linear layout contains more no.of items(means more views are there like List view). but the problem is only 2 relative layouts are working(means when you click on the relative layout then it will shown the linear layout) and remaining one is not working(that code part is not executed). Suppose we are changing the order(means first you can write the Linear Layout1,Linear layout3 and after Linear layout 2) then LL1 and L3 are working LL2 is not working. How to handle it?

and one more thing i got web service error is "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException".

please can anybody help me.

thanks

Comment: Sky has no limit , same way assumption for your question has no limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` type of Error means Array size index is not available.

Ex :- Array size is 2 then index call at 3rd position then this type of error comes.

so please check your code accordingly .

Comment: Here Linear layouts acts like a List view. First load the Linear layouts using WS response. Only 2 Linear Layouts(any 2 Linear layouts means Suppose coding order is LL1,LL2,LL3 then LL1,LL2 are executed and LL3 coding part is not executed. Coding order is LL1,LL3,LL2 then LL1,LL3 are executed and LL2 coding part is not executed.) are Loaded. is it clear to You? what is the reason